# Same dll files in my computer is x64, but on another computer they are x86, strange

Tags: dll, x86, 64-bit, dependency-walker

I have an program which has the dependencies of `MSVCP100D.DLL` and `MSVCR100D.DLL`, x64 version.

This is the screenshot of [DependencyWalker](http://dependencywalker.com) in **my** computer:

[image]

When I copy this program to my friend's computer, it can't run since there are no such two files. Then I copied the 2 dll files to his computer.

But it reports some error when executing the program, and when I use dependency walker to check, I found a very strange thing. This is screenshot from him:

[image]

Why they are "x64" in my computer and "x86" in his computer? How to fix it?

---

**Update**

My friend's system is win7 x64 too.

Comment: You have a 64 bits machine, and he has a 32 bits machine.

Comment: The file sizes are different, these aren't the same files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after several hours, we fixed it. There are too many strange things.

First. My system is win7 x64.

Here take `MSVCP100D.DLL` for example. There are two different MSVCP100D.DLL in my computer, one in `windows/system32`, one in `windows/SysWOW64`. They have different sizes.

Look at the screenshots:
[image]

But in "everything" they have same sizes(even same modified date), that I thought they are the same.

[image]

Then I send the dll from system32 via an IM software called QQ.

I dragged the file from `windoes/system32` which is 991K, but QQ displayed the size is "726K":

[image]

But, if I copy the file into another dir, e.g. `D:\`, then send it again, the size is correct "991K".

Finally, I copied these dll files into another dir, and package them into zip file, they are sent correctly, and the program run well on my friends' computer.

Comment: You should read about Windows 64-bit file redirection, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx